# How can i print number instead of class label and score on image with object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am a student and learning deep learning. I am having a project and using object_detection_tutorial (code below) to detect diseases of rice plant. I want to print number of position where have diseases instead of class label and score (**like image below**), but i don't know how. So i really need help to solve this. Thanks you.

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
        for i in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
            image = Image.open(i)
            image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
            image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
            (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
                 [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
                 feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
            vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(image_np,np.squeeze(boxes),
                                                         np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                                                         np.squeeze(scores),
                                                         category_index,
                                                         use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                                                         line_thickness=2)
            cv2.imshow("image_np", image_np)
            cv2.waitKey()
```

i want to print image like below
image_result:

[image: image_result]

Comment: you should better include the image rather redirecting to another site

Comment: maybe the code of detectron can help you, look for the code at github.

Comment: thanks Ahmed Emad.

Comment: FesianXu, can you give detail suggets for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this has little to do with openCV and it's probably tensorflow code.

If I am not mistaken the code uses this function from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py#L784). Running the above code it returns `(boxes, scores, classes, num)` which correspond to the bounding boxes along with the corresponding confidence score and class id and the number of detection (which is not really helpful in your case).

Assuming (a you say that `dao_on` is the class name) that the displayed message contains the class name and the score I am guessing you are thrown to line:

```
display_str = str(class_name)
```

Anyway, the easiest way for you would be to copy this function, `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array()` (it's auxiliary and it's not actual tensorflow) and replace all code referring to the displayed string with the string you want. That is the number of objects being detected I guess? If you have just one class then:

```
for i in range(min(max_boxes_to_draw, boxes.shape[0])):
    # delete all code in the block
    display_str = i

# Draw all boxes onto image.
  for box, color in box_to_color_map.items():
```

OpenCV is not really used apart from displaying the image I think.

Comment: Thanks, but i have 4 classes, and if on an image has more than one diseased position with one or more class, i want to increase number (from 1 to all) at each diseased position no matter what class it is. So how i should do.

Comment: Please make a bit clearer what are you asking exactly. I didn't get it. If there are more deceased position e.g. 2 from different classes how should they by labeled?

Comment: sorry about didn't give you clearly questions. I have solved the problem by following your suggestion. Thanks very much.

Comment: If you find the answer useful you can accept so that other people know this question has a working solution (and possibly upvote also).